# Are questions from Google Code Jam, TopCoder, etc. on-topic?

Tags: discussion, policy, scope

The [original proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles) is for "Code Golf and Programming Puzzles". I think this suggests that discussion of questions from programming contests should indeed be on-topic---as long as they're not discussed until the conclusion of the contest, of course.

This question serves as a placeholder for official policy in this area, as well as what kind of timeframes we should enforce on such questions (e.g., discussion of active contest questions should probably be disallowed).

Comment: As a related topic, my feeling is that things like Facebook Puzzles probably should not be discussed in depth, since these questions generally do not expire. We should also have some policies in this area.

Comment: What about problems from SPOJ, UVa, Project Euler and the like? Those questions also do not expire, should they too be not allowed here? That would make this place a lot less interesting IMHO. I agree we shouldn't just post solutions, but discussion would be good.

Comment: @MAK: I agree. We should create policies that draw a line between what is or isn't acceptable.

Comment: Related question: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5/site-title-and-domain @Chris Can you open the related topic as a separate question? It's worth discussing in the likely event that we widen scope.

Comment: @marcog: Will do. :-)

Comment: @marcog: Posted: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16/what-are-the-policies-for-threads-relating-to-facebook-puzzles-project-euler-uv

Comment: Oops, already answered here )

Comment: I don't think an otherwise on-topic and well-defined puzzle/challenge should be closed or discouraged just because it may be part of a contest. We're not the morality police, nor are we responsible for enforcing the terms of every contest that exists.

Answer (score 2):

Answer on this question is rather obvious for me.
We may not to ask (and may close) questions which can be used for contests:

1. Unexpiring: *Yesterday I registered on this contest site, today searched all this stackexchange and tomorrow I will be at **the top of scoreboard**! Yeay!!1*
2. Expiring: *Hey I **want to win** this contest! I have two days to the end! Help me!*

**But!** If it is unexpiring contest (such as ProjectEuler), we can discuss solution in way of pseudocode and textual algorithm describing, diagrams etc. instead of code posting. It's just to make man to be able to discuss, research and write on his own, not just copy-pate-F9.

And if contest is already **over and doesn't have any working scoreboard** (like ICFPC, but don't sure about 2010, because they promised to keep it online), we may discuss it on 100% with code and anything else.

Comment: Re answer being "rather obvious": Most of my policy-related questions are Socratic in nature---they're probably obvious to most people here too, but having a discussion keeps everyone on the same page. :-)

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young, agree with you at 100%, the obviousness here wasn't the main idea of my answer )

Comment: I don't think an otherwise on-topic and well-defined puzzle/challenge should be closed or discouraged just because it may be part of a contest.  We're not the morality police, nor are we responsible for enforcing the terms of every contest that exists.

Answer (score -1):

TopCoder and possibly CodeJam problems are probably excluded because I expect their terms of use would disallow reproduction without explicitly granted permission.

Comment: You *might* be right about TopCoder, but I'd like someone to confirm this. For those, we just include a link to the question. CodeJam has no statement about this, so this doesn't hold true.

Comment: Problem statements and test sets are protected by copyright. However, ideas are not. So rephrasing a problem statement and providing new input sets would not be a violation. See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892126/file-fix-it-codegolf-gcj-2010-1b-a