# Will golf and puzzle questions migrate here from SO?

Tags: discussion

As far as I remember, one of (unstrict, as we can see) Area51 rules was that *we will not create sites, witch may took part of SO's audience*. For example, by this rule Ruby.stackexchange was declined.
But today this site was launched and CodeReview was also spotted. So, will moderators migrate `codegolf`, `puzzle` etc. tag questions here or they may stay a part of *history*?

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps there's a standard SE policy on this? I know some questions were migrated to programmers.se when it launched, but mod @ChrisF is weary of migrating too many there.

Comment: I think this site should be able to grow from ground up, but, on the other hand, some questions on SO are indeed interesting enough to migrate here. So, I'd advocate being selective.

Comment: Just noting, nearly all such questions will be CW on SO and there's no way to revert CW. This might make imported questions a bit odd here.

Comment: Questions won't really get migrated en-masse until the site proves itself as a full-fledged beta graduate. Then they will get migrated.

Comment: @marcog: In theory mods now have the power to revert CW. However, we have had some trouble with that on this site.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how this site would rob much from SO.  Most problems here are asinine in a real-world setting, and if anyone actually golfs for anything other than kicks, they should be shot.

Sure, the occasional question is fairly interesting and dare-I-say useful (move those to SO?).  Nevertheless, I think your view of this site is somewhat rosy.

Comment: You may have misunderstood the question. Code-golf had a special remit on Stack Overflow (most "challenge" type questions were closed), and there are about 200 existing code-golf questions there. New code golf obviously belongs here, but Nakilon is asking about the fate of the old ones. Especially as several have been duplicated on this site.