# Can we restrict golfing questions to a particular language?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

If I have a golfing challenge, but I want it done in a specific language, can I specify that? Does this go against the general spirit of golfing to restrict people in the languages which they can use?

I say this because some problems are easy given even basic operators like addition and multiplication, but become a little more fun when you have to improvise with brainfuck or fish or something. Perhaps could I at least limit them to use a stack based language?

Comment: Hate to close-as-dupe your question quite so soon, but it really, really does feel like a duplicate of the linked question. If there's something that you feel needs addressing beyond that question, please edit your question appropriately and I'll reopen the question.