# What should the policy be on questions currently being used for recruiting?

Tags: discussion, policy

Companies sometimes hold mini programming contests in order to select potential employees based on the answers they give. We've already had 2 questions ([this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/400/correctly-implement-the-exon-chaining-algorithm) and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266/nokia-mystery-puzzle)) of this type.

Clearly some of these questions may be interesting, but should we treat them the same as we treat questions from currently running contests?

Related Questions:

- [Are questions from Google Code Jam, TopCoder, etc. on-topic?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-questions-from-google-code-jam-topcoder-etc-on-topic)
- [What are the policies for threads relating to Facebook Puzzles, Project Euler, UVa, SPOJ, etc.?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/what-are-the-policies-for-threads-relating-to-facebook-puzzles-project-euler-uv)

Answer (score 8):

Absolutely they should be posted here. Some of the questions are quite fun, and if the companies are smart, they will come over here and see how much better our answers are :)

One day they might learn they should just post the questions here themselves and recruit from here